# sparkContext.wholeTextFiles(location) does not throw exception for absent path until action is performed

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am reading data present in hour format present in S3 through spark.For example,

> sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("s3://'Bucket'/'key'/'yyyy'/'MM'/'dd'/'hh'/*").

The above method returns a (key,value) pair which is (Filename,Content).

**Issue**

sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("location").values returns an RDD which does not throw exception if the 'location' in S3 is not present until an action is performed on this RDD.

**Current code to check whether location given is present or not**

```
 val data = sparkSession.sparkContext
  .wholeTextFiles(location)
  .values
Try {
  data.isEmpty()
}
 case Success(_)=>{}
 case Failure(_)=>{}
```

Return value for ***data*** even if location is not present:  ***MapPartitionsRDD[2]***

Return value after performing ***isEmpty()*** action on ***data*** is

> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist:

**Question**

I am using a kind of hack to perform an action ***isEmpty()*** (I can used any other action too)on ***data*** RDD to give Failure in case the location is not present otherwise if this check is not done then it fails and throws the same above exception when this data is used later due to lazy evaluation.

**I wanted to ask if this is the right approach to check whether the location is present to read data as an action is needed to be performed on RDD?**

Answer (score 1):

Generally, in short, decision making on exceptions is not the best strategy.

you can use Hadoop's `FileSystem` API to check paths first before you start the processing through spark.

Spark processes things lazily. That's the expected behavior and the reason why you get the error when an action is performed.

Comment: Checking whether file exists or not using the hadoop filesystem api is the way to go. Handling the exception and making it work is not good.